# tableview selection indication doesn't remain after reloadData when editing

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8

I have a `UITableView` in a `UIViewController`. It's Selection modes are set to `Single` and `Multiple Selection During Editing`.

When I set the tableView's `editing` property to `YES`, if a process asynchronously runs `reloadData`, any of my current check marks that have been selected disappear. I implemented my `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method such that it sets the `selected` property of the cell, based on what the selection was before the `reloadData`. I've verified those **are** being set correctly. But to no avail, they still don't show up selected. What do I need to change so that it gets that set correctly? It seems to retain the indented editing mode just fine.

Here's said method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ValveCell";
    ValveCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    Valve *valve = self.sections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row];
    cell.subject = valve;
    cell.selected = [self.selections member: valve];
    return cell;
}
```

I use the didSelect and didDeselect methods to keep `selections` (an `NSMutableSet`) up to date. E.g.

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSMutableArray *section = self.sections[indexPath.section];
    [self.selections removeObject: section[indexPath.row]];
}
```

### Clarification

Given the answers, I think I did not clarify which check marks I was referring to. I am referring to the blue check marks that show a selected state on the *left* side of the table when the table has had its `editing` set to `YES` as shown in this picture:

[image]

If a `reloadData` occurs, it will clear those blue check marks.

### Update: My Current Solution

What I did to retain the visual selection status is to modify the KVO method that was firing the `reloadData` to include code to programmatically reselect the current selections:

```
...
[self.tableView reloadData];
if (self.tableView.editing) {
    [self.sections enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id valves, NSUInteger section, BOOL *stop) {
         [(NSArray*)valves enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id valve, NSUInteger row, BOOL *stop) {
             if ([self.selections member: valve]) {
                 NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: row inSection: section];
                 [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath animated: NO scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
             }
         }];
    }];
}
...
```

The `selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:` method does the work.

So at this point, I guess my question is, do I really have to do this? Or I'm working too hard?

Comment: Could you post the code of your cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: Where are you setting the checkmarks? If it's in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` isn't going to be called just because you set selected to YES in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. You need to either have the checkmarks set in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` dependent on the self.selections array or call `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` manually if the cell's selected from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: No, you're definitely working too hard. In response to the added code: (1) What is "member:" in this line `[self.selections member: valve];` on `cellForRowAtIndexPath`? And (2) why are you removing the index with this line `[self.selections removeObject: section[indexPath.row]];` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`? (This is where the problem lies and why the check used to disappear on reload data. There's a problem with your data structure.)

Comment: Because I'm maintaining an `NSSet` of what's selected in my ViewController. So as the delegate methods indicated the user has selected/deselected (when in editing mode) fire, I keep that up controller side set up to date. However, when the `reloadData` happens, then I'm programmatically replaying what to select. If that delegate callback were firing on `reloadData`, I wouldn't be able to replay them (the set would be emptied). But that's verifiably not happening. The delegate does not fire on a reload. And the set isn't empty, or my solution wouldn't have worked.

Comment: What I'm saying is that your data structure (NSSet/NSArray/...) should immediately dictate the contents of your UITableView upon reloadData. I see what you're doing now... In the member of your NSSet at the current indexPath is empty, you set the cell as NOT selected. And I haven't seen your didSelectRowAtIndexPath, but I assume you add to the set in order to do the opposite. (If you could post didSelectRowAtIndexPath I could verify.) con't...

Comment: When you say "the delegate does not fire on a reload" which delegate method are you referring to? And how are the actual checkmarks added to the cell? Because simply saying "cell.selected =..." doesn't result in any delegate calls, for example it doesn't force a call to didSelectRowAtIndexPath or didDeselectRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Assumption about didSelect: correct. What I found though, was that setting `selected` on the cell will not cause the cell to have the blue check mark there. I have since removed that part, because just setting it would not get it to show up.

Comment: So where are you setting the blue check mark?

Comment: When I tap on it (in editing mode), it just shows up. I don't have to set it in response to user action. That part is just for free apparently (which is inconsistent with how Apple does the "normal" right said selection pattern).

Comment: Could you post your didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66077/discussion-between-travis-griggs-and-lyndsey-scott).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the cell to "selected" in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` won't force a call to the `UITableView` delegate methods so if that's where you're setting your checkmarks, they won't automatically appear upon the table view's reload.

You can either add the checkmarks directly in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, ex:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ValveCell";
    ValveCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    Valve *valve = self.sections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row];
    cell.subject = valve;
    cell.selected = [self.selections member: valve];

    if (cell.selected) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Or you can call `selectRowAtIndexPath` manually, ex:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ValveCell";
    ValveCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    Valve *valve = self.sections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row];
    cell.subject = valve;
    cell.selected = [self.selections member: valve];

    if (cell.selected) {
        [self tableView:tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone]; 
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: See my Clarification. Setting the `accessoryType` affects the right side icons, not the ones that slide in from the left when you're in editing mode. Sorry for the confusion.